# How to upload image files in Postman and echo back the same image using Express and Multer

Tags: node.js, express, postman, multipartform-data, multer

I am trying to upload a product using postman and anytime I submit; it sends back all the data with the image `undefined` as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Postman output]

My controller file:

```
const gameRepository = require("../routes/repository")

exports.createGame = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const PORT = 8000;
        const hostname = req.hostname;
        const url = req.protocol + '://' + hostname + ':' + PORT + req.path;

        const payload = ({
            name: req.body.name,
            price: req.body.price,
            category: req.body.category,
            gameIsNew: req.body.gameIsNew,
            topPrice: req.body.topPrice,
            isVerOrient: req.body.IsVerOrient,
            description: req.body.description,
            image: url + '/imgs/' + req.path
        });          
        
        let eachGame = await gameRepository.createGame({
            ...payload
        });

        console.log(req.body)

        res.status(200).json({
            status: true,
            data: eachGame,
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err,
            status: false,
        })
    }
}
```

`repository.js`:

```
const Game = require("../models/gameModel");

exports.games = async () => {
    const games = await Game.find();
    return games;
}

exports.gameById = async id => {
    const game = await Game.findById(id);
    return game;
}

exports.createGame = async payload => {
    const newGame = await Game.create(payload);
    return newGame;
}

exports.removeGame = async id => {
    const game = await Game.findById(id);
    return game;
}
```

`Multer.js`:

```
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");

// checking for file type
const MIME_TYPES = {
    'imgs/jpg': 'jpg',
    'imgs/jpeg': 'jpeg',
    'imgs/png': 'png'
}

// Image Upload
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb ) => {
        cb(null, path.join('../imgs'));
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const name = file.originalname.split('').join(__);
        const extension = MIME_TYPES[file.mimetype];
        cb(null, name + new Date().toISOString() + '.' + extension);
    }
});

module.exports = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 6
    },
})
```

I am not sure about where I went wrong, that is why I need an external eye to help locate where the fault is coming from.

I have a feeling that I need to use `body-parser` or navigate into the image folder correctly, or multi-part form, I am not sure.

Comment: You mentioned multer for file upload but your code does not show a multer middleware. Please add enough code to make the example easier to debug.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out! 
I added the / to image and I still got the same results. And do you suggest i remove  const url = req.protocol + '://' + hostname + req.body.path; ?

Comment: I have added the codes from other files to provide more information.

Comment: your url is broken @GODSWILL it shoud read `const url = req.protocol + '://' + hostname + ":" + PORT + req.path`. You are using `req.body.path` and you can see itis broken as it returns undefined in your screenshot. You should use `req.path` or `req.originalUrl` depending on the parts of url object you are interested in

Comment: Thank you @rags2riches, Do I have to create a new variable for PORT?

Comment: @GODSWILL yes, it's the port your server is listening to. In your first snippet just declare and initialise const PORT = 3000 (whatever is the port number) and then use it in your const url. Make sure you also change the payload image property to reflect the url for the image...clear?

Comment: @GODSWILL now the question is, what is the real problem here, the broken path or else?

Comment: I followed the instruction you provided me with but i get:    "image": "http://localhost:8000/game/imgs//game"  in postman and there's no image in my "imgs" folder. I will edit my code to show you what i did

Comment: @rags2riches the problem now is when I upload; I get the data submitted to MongoDB but the image is not included and it is not reflecting in the folder I created for the images in my work directory

Comment: but is the url now displaying correctly?

Comment: I am not sure what the correct is but I have:   "image": "http://localhost:8000/game/imgs//game"  with the game showing twice. Is that right?

Comment: @GODSWILL this line in your payload...image: url + '/imgs/' + req.path should now be just image: url. You have already built the url for this previously

Comment: @GODSWILL the image does not show in postman because you are sending the payload back but not the image. Multer is set up correctly but you are not using it to upload the image anywhere in the code you have showed

Comment: @rags2riches can you suggest a solution to make it work? how do I configure the code correctly to upload the image?

Comment: @rags2riches I kept getting  "error": "Multipart: Boundary not found",  here is a github repo https://github.com/Godswill199/scratch9ja.git

Comment: @rags2riches Thank you very much for your help. I figured it out.  the mistake was from the callback function of storage in the multer.js file.
mistake:  ```  cb(null, `${new Date().toISOString()}.${extension}`);   ``` 

correction: ```   cb(null, `${new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g,'-')}.${extension}`);  ```

I added the colons in the date of my image with the hyphen in the callback function of storage. I will edit my question to the working code.
Thanks a lot, @AbrarHossain and @rags2riches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after many try and fail I finally figured it out.
turns out it has compatibility issues depending on your OS.

I use windows 10 and this resolved the issue for me

Here is my working code:

multer.js

```
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");


// checking for file type
const MIME_TYPES = {
    'image/jpg': 'jpg',
    'image/jpeg': 'jpeg',
    'image/png': 'png'
}

// Image Upload
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb ) => {
      cb(null, ('storage/imgs/'));
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const extension = MIME_TYPES[file.mimetype];
    
    // I added the colons in the date of my image with the hyphen 
        cb(null, `${new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g,'-')}.${extension}`);
    }
});

module.exports = multer({
    storage: storage
})
```

In my controller.js

```
const gameRepository = require("../routes/repository");

exports.createGame = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const payload = {
      name: req.body.name,
      price: req.body.price,
      category: req.body.category,
      gameIsNew: req.body.gameIsNew,
      topPrice: req.body.topPrice,
      isVerOrient: req.body.IsVerOrient,
      description: req.body.description,
      image: req.file.filename,
    };

    let eachGame = await gameRepository.createGame({
      ...payload,
    });
    
    res.status(200).json({
      status: true,
      data: eachGame,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({
      error: err,
      status: false,
    });
  }
};

exports.getGames = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let games = await gameRepository.games();
    res.status(200).json({
      status: true,
      data: games,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({
      error: err,
      status: false,
    });
  }
};

exports.getGameById = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let id = req.params.id;
    let gameDetails = await gameRepository.gameById(id);
    req.req.status(200).json({
      status: true,
      data: gameDetails,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
      status: false,
      error: err,
    });
  }
};

exports.removeGame = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let id = req.params.id;
    let gameDetails = await gameRepository.removeGame(id);
    res.status(200).json({
      status: true,
      data: gameDetails,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
      status: false,
      data: err,
    });
  }
};
```

:

[Postman output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIxvQ.png)

Thanks to this great community.